# Website login loading endlessly when I use find_element()

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm having a problem with Selenium, when fetching an input from a login from a page. For some reason, whenever I store the element in a variable, the site in question, when trying to log in, keeps loading infinitely. However, if I remove that part of the code, and enter the login credentials manually, the login is done normally. I will explain below:

This is how the page input I try to access looks like:

```
<input id="txtUsername" name="txtUsername" class="random-name" placeholder="User" type="text" required="required" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">

<input id="txtPassword" name="txtUsername" class="random-name" placeholder="User" type="text" required="required" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
```

And this is my python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import chrome
from time import sleep


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
site = "www.google.com"
browser.get(site)


def make_login(browser):
    sleep(1)
    login = browser.find_element(By.ID, "txtUsername")
    login.click()
    login_text = "User"
    for x in login_text:
        sleep(0.15)
        login.send_keys(x)
    senha = navegador.find_element(By.ID, "txtPassword")
    senha.click()
    senha_text = "Password"
    for x in senha_text:
        sleep(0.15)
        senha.send_keys(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    make_login(browser)
```

When I run it, it clicks on each input, enters the password, as it should. However, when I click log in, the website keeps loading endlessly.

If i remove this part:

```
login = browser.find_element(By.ID, "txtUsername")
login.click()

senha = navegador.find_element(By.ID, "txtPassword")
senha.click()
```

And manually clicking on the inputs, he enters the site normally...
I appreciate anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use only use `send_keys()`? So, your code will look like:

```
def make_login(browser):
    sleep(1)
    login = browser.find_element(By.ID, "txtUsername")
    login_text = "User"
    login.send_keys(login_text)
    senha = navegador.find_element(By.ID, "txtPassword")
    senha_text = "Password"
    senha.send_keys(senha_text)
```

As shown in [selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) `send_keys()` method is enough to fill input fields.

But if you're trying to access sites like [bet365](https://www.bet365.com) it's almost certainly the website prohibiting your code. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69695721/how-to-login-to-bet365-using-selenium-python) and its answers.

Comment: Good learning, I thought I would have to click() before using send_keys(), but even trying this way in the answer, it didn't work. Again I commented out the lines where I used find_element(), ran it again, and manually logged in, which worked.

Comment: I see. Can you put more information in your question? Maybe the rest of the code will help solve the problem.

Comment: Yes I can, but I believe the rest of the code won't change in the problem, I've already isolated this to test outside the main file and the problem continues.

Comment: How you're selecting and clicking the login button?

Comment: I was clicking on the button manually, but I already did by finding the element and using click(), if I can't solve it, I would at least understand why it works manually and not by selenium, I just think the site is identifying and blocking it.

Comment: Can you say the site you're trying to login?

Comment: Yes, https://casino.bet365.com/Play/LiveSuperSpinRoulette

Comment: Understood. In this case, it is almost certainly the website prohibiting your code. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69695721/how-to-login-to-bet365-using-selenium-python) and it's answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking through the thread and found the undetected-chromedriver library, installed it, passed the code and now it works!!!

Comment: Ow, what good notice! I'll update the answer and put this information! Appreciate your vote on my suggestion!!!